# HDMI TV not showing as audio output in System Preferences

Tags: audio, hdmi

I have linked a cable from my MacBook Air to my TV via HDMI but cannot get volume on the TV. I have gone into preferences-sound but their is no facility to change 'internal speakers'. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a Mini Displayport to HDMI adapter [this](http://forums.creativecow.net/thread/8/1149273) should help you.  If you are using Mini-DVI to HDMI adapter then you will have to get audio from your headphone port via an external cable because DVI is strictly video.

Comment: because I am not tech savvy I assume that the little adapter I purchased from Mac Book Air is not sufficient to power audo to TV.    Because I cannot change 'audio output' on Mac perhaps it will never work and I will need the eternal speaker via headphone port???